# Python .csv writer

Tags: python, csv, writer

I use a `.writer()` method in a loop, as shown in the Python documentation.
I want to write the results of the variable `u`, row by row (or better line by line).

Actually it works perfectly in the interpreter but the module `writerow()` doesn't seem to work. Why?

```
from urlparse import urlparse
import csv
import re

ifile =open(ipath,'r')
ofile = open(opath, 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(ofile, dialect='excel')

url =[urlparse(u).netloc for u in file (ipath, "r+b")]
sitesource =  set([re.sub("www.", "", e) for e in url])
liste = [re.split(",'", e) for e in liste]


ofile
for row in file (ifile) :
    for u in sitesource:
        print ("Creation de:", u)
        writer.writerow(u) 

ofile.close()
```

I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: Does the python interpreter throw an error or what is the issue? BTW you're printing the value of variable "u", but you're writing the letter "u" to the csv. Is that what you want?

Comment: No error in the interpreter. I want print the value of the variable u. BTW the file doesn't seem to be opened.

Comment: What is the result you are seeing ? Is ofile empty ? Put the file opens in a try,except block and see if there is any IOError being thrown when you are trying to open the files (ifile,ofile) . If there is no IOError , check if is sitesource an empty ? print its contents and see if it has any values.

Comment: may be you are not writing the terminating character ? This is how i create the writer object
Writer = csv.writer(open(sys.argv[2], 'wb'), delimiter=',',quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

Comment: `for row in file (ifile) :` is incorrect.  `ifile` is already open, so it should be `for row in ifile:`

Comment: Also, you iterate over each `row`, but then don't use it.  Why?

Comment: `u` is a string.  `writerow` expects a sequence of strings.

Comment: I don't see you using `liste` after assignment.  Perhaps you forgot to delete that line from your example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guessing at you really mean, I would rewrite your code as follows:

```
from urlparse import urlparse
import csv
import re

ifile =open(ipath,'r')
ofile = open(opath, 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(ofile, dialect='excel')

url =[urlparse(u).netloc for u in ifile]
sitesource =  set([re.sub("www.", "", e) for e in url])

for u in sitesource:
    print ("Creation de:", u)
    writer.writerow([u]) 

ofile.close()
ifile.close()
```

I deleted `liste` as it's not used.  I got rid of `for row in file (ifile):` as you already iterated over its contents when you created `url`.

I changed

```
url =[urlparse(u).netloc for u in file (ipath, "r+b")]
```

to

```
url =[urlparse(u).netloc for u in ifile]
```

because you already had the file open.  I assumed you did not want binary mode if you are reading strings.

I changed `writerow(u)` to write a sequence: `writerow([u])`.  This puts a single `u` per line, which means your csv file will not acutally have any commas in it.  If you wanted all of your results in a single row, replace the final loop with this statment `writer.writerow(sitesource)`.

Comment: Thanks I just create a new .csv make the same change than you, and it works. Because > url =[urlparse(u).netloc for u in ifile]
because you already had the file open. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

`writerow()` expects a sequence argument, so I think you need to use `writer.writerow([u])` since each `u` is a single string -- otherwise you're passing it a sequence of characters doing it the way you currently have it.

Comment: ok I've done a change and give it a sequence argument quitting the split fonction. It return a list of simplified url in a list set set(['', 'alain-bazot.fr', 'blog.lefigaro.fr', 'humeursdejeandornac.blogspot.com', 'lefigaro.fr', 'machronique.com', 'lemoci.com', 'france-amerique.com', 'agriculture.gouv.fr']) but still no way to write it in a csv file

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to write the string "u"? or the contents of the variable ? If it's the latter option, then remove the parentheses.

Comment: I want to write the content of the variable u by printing it in the interpreter it gives me the values of the the variable u. But when I try it in blank with a simple string such as writer.writerow("blabla"). Doesn't work. It seems that it's the module csv that doesn't work... but i put at the begin import csv.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure, but csv.writer.writerow wants a sequence (i always use it with lists) with the fields for the whole row, and you are iterating over a set of what which returns what in u?

Comment: There is no type error in the interpreter. I use the print function to check if it was relevant or not. But maybe you're right it one point: writerow want maybe "," to return the whole row. Butthe function write doesn't work at all...

Comment: So what values do you get for the variable "u"?